# Python code to print a dictionary in Jinja2 templating

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm trying to print a dictionary that looks like for e.g.
groups = {'place': ABC, 'name': XYZ , 'IP': ['1.1.1.1','2.2.2.2']}
in a table in Jinja2 templating format:
I've a word document that looks like this for now:
[image]
I know this isn't how it is supposed to look and I'm stuck as I'm a complete beginner in Jinja2. Could someone help me out here? I want to know how I can modify my table in the word document to get the required result.

PS: The code on the word document currently is:

```
{% tr for key,value in groups.items() %} {{key}}    {% for elem in value %}{{ elem }}{% if value|length > 0 and value.index(elem) != value|length-1 %} {%endif%}{% endfor %} {%tr endfor %}
```

Essentially my dict should look like:

| Place | Name | IP |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | XYZ | 1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2 |

The table in the image attached is what I tried for now, but it throws errors

Comment: please add the code you tried to run so we can help you debug it

Comment: @MarkKapilyan The python code is just the dictionary that I already have. I just need to print it out on the word document. So the code on the word document is what I need help with.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      {% for key in groups.keys() %}
      <th>{{ key|title }}</th>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      {% for key in groups.keys() %}
      <td>{{ groups[key]}}</td>
      {% endfor %}
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```